# Bind an input with type datetime-local to a Date property in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, binding

It is possible to bind a component property of Date type to a HTML5 input with type set to `datetime-local`?

In my component I have a poperty:

```
public filterDateFrom: Date;
```

and in my template I have an input defined as:

```
<input type="datetime-local" [(ngModel)]="filterDateFrom" />
```

but binding doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the [] around ng-model? The common bind is `ng-model="nameOfTheVarFromscopeOrPropertie"`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[Demo Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BK6q5dTenMwxSRq3f8JX?p=preview)

You can bind to a date using the following format: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm`, which you can also get from `date.toISOString().slice(0,16)` (the slice removes the time portion after the minutes).

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<input type="datetime-local" [value]="date" 
          (change)="date=$event.target.value" /> {{date}}` 
})
export class AppComponent {
    date: string;
    constructor() {
        this.date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 16);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `date.toISOString()` will return a date offset from local time.  You can also construct the date string yourself:

```
private toDateString(date: Date): string {
    return (date.getFullYear().toString() + '-' 
       + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' 
       + ("0" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2))
       + 'T' + date.toTimeString().slice(0,5);
}
```

If you want to be able to bind the select to a `Date` model, you can use this to build a custom date component:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-date',
    events: ['dateChange'],
    template: `<input type="datetime-local" [value] = "_date" 
             (change) = "onDateChange($event.target.value)" />`
})
export class MyDate{
    private _date: string;
    @Input() set date(d: Date) {
        this._date = this.toDateString(d);
    }
    @Output() dateChange: EventEmitter<Date>;
    constructor() {
        this.date = new Date();
        this.dateChange = new EventEmitter();       
    }

    private toDateString(date: Date): string {
        return (date.getFullYear().toString() + '-' 
           + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' 
           + ("0" + (date.getDate())).slice(-2))
           + 'T' + date.toTimeString().slice(0,5);
    }

    private parseDateString(date:string): Date {
       date = date.replace('T','-');
       var parts = date.split('-');
       var timeParts = parts[3].split(':');

      // new Date(year, month [, day [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
      return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2], timeParts[0], timeParts[1]);     // Note: months are 0-based

    }

    private onDateChange(value: string): void {
        if (value != this._date) {
            var parsedDate = this.parseDateString(value);

            // check if date is valid first
            if (parsedDate.getTime() != NaN) {
               this._date = value;
               this.dateChange.emit(parsedDate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Users of your component would bind to a `Date` model with two-way model binding:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [MyDate],
    template: '<my-date [(date)]="date"></my-date>  {{date}}' 
})
export class AppComponent {
    @Input() date: Date;
    constructor() {
        this.date = new Date();
    }
}
```

Or if you want to avoid custom tags, rewrite the component as a directive:

```
<input type="datetime-local" [(date)]="date" />
```

[Demo Plnkr with Directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/9nMxggSXMW0pK30XK24i?p=preview)

Comment: it works, but after binding it (using a directive), clicking to up & down arrows on control doesn't work correctly - when I have selected a hour sub-field, clicking to up-arrow increases hour +2 instead of +1 and when I have selected a minute subfield, clicking to up-arrow increases minute +1 and also hour +1

Comment: on which device / browser?

Comment: Google Chrome 47.0 on Windows (desktop)

Comment: Fixed parsing logic - see updated plnkr.  toDateString() and parseDateString() should be complementary: the first formats a date to yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm format, the second parses it back to a Date object.

Comment: Been a while your component seems nice, but how would you go updating the value when the value is lazy loaded? When set through ngModel at a later stage the value shows as empty.

You can try this by wrapping the date = in a setTimeout

Comment: Did you try your plunker under FFox and IE ? 
// Firefox 54: seems javascript use doc.write and result is an invalid tree.. 
// IE (10, or Edge mode): plunker is not working (parse error: maybe polyfills..) 
// I finally swith to another component: https://github.com/vlio20/angular-datepicker

Comment: saved my life. slice(0, 16) remove the time after mins. now my datetime variable can be binded on ngModal.

Answer (score 21):

Now that its Spring 2017, `DatePipe` is shipped OOTB.  You can achieve (one-way) binding by specifying format parameters to the pipe.  For example:

```
<input type="datetime-local" [ngModel]="filterDateFrom | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'" />
```

Slight caveat is that you can not use two-way binding with this technique, you have to use one way binding with the data pipe, then manage the DOM to model change events to handle client changes to the control (unless I'm missing something!), but it seems a lot cleaner this way.

---

### Update

Looks like I was indeed missing something!

Adding `ngModelChange` to the above should provide the DOM --> model side of the two-way binding process:

```
<input type="datetime-local" 
       [ngModel]="filterDateFrom | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'"
       (ngModelChange)="filterDateFrom = $event" />
```

Comment: I like this approach, but this has a drawback for me:
`filterDateFrom` is type Date, but `(ngModelChange)="filterDateFrom = $event"` assigns a string. (and thus also the timezone is off)

Comment: @ne1410s i tried your sample but i need to show LongTime format  for 24 hours

Comment: I think this is the best answer! Instead of `(ngModelChange)="filterDateFrom = $event"` I created a custom function to transform the `filterDateFrom` into a Date Object. `(ngModelChange)="setDateFrom($event)"`  and the function is something like `setDateFrom(e: string) { filterDateFrom = new Date(e) }` (I also treated when the date was invalid `if (e.trim() !== "")`)

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by @ne1410s answer I ended doing something very similar but without losing the date type.

I used a pipe to declare the `ngModel` and call a method `dateChanged` just to return the conversion of the new Date in the `ts`.

html code:

```
<input type="datetime-local" [ngModel]="filterDateFrom | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm'" (ngModelChange)="filterDateFrom = dateChanged($event)"/>
```

ts code:

```
 dateChanged(eventDate: string): Date | null {
   return !!eventDate ? new Date(eventDate) : null;
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

I was looking into this problem as well and started to go down this examples road. However, you can use [(ngModel)] on an input of the type [date,datetime,datetime-local]. The key is to match the expected format the control is expecting. In this case it expects [this format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3339). Which also means the type that you bind to the control needs to be a string. I have provided an example [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4TQctt), that demonstrates how to use [(ngModel)].

```js
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
      <form>
        <input type="datetime-local" [(ngModel)]="dateTimeLocal"><br />
        {{dateTimeLocal}}
      </form>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  private _dateTimeLocal: Date;

  constructor() {
    this._dateTimeLocal = new Date();
  }

  private parseDateToStringWithFormat(date: Date): string {
    let result: string;
    let dd = date.getDate().toString();
    let mm = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
    let hh = date.getHours().toString();
    let min = date.getMinutes().toString();
    dd = dd.length === 2 ? dd : "0" + dd;
    mm = mm.length === 2 ? mm : "0" + mm;
    hh = hh.length === 2 ? hh : "0" + hh;
    min = min.length === 2 ? min : "0" + min;
    result = [date.getFullYear(), '-', mm, '-', dd, 'T', hh, ':', min].join('');

    return result;
  }

  public set dateTimeLocal(v: string) {
    let actualParsedDate = v ? new Date(v) : new Date();
    let normalizedParsedDate = new Date(actualParsedDate.getTime() + (actualParsedDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000));
    this._dateTimeLocal = normalizedParsedDate;
  }


  public get dateTimeLocal(): string {
    return this.parseDateToStringWithFormat(this._dateTimeLocal);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Dan Simon should your bound property not be named '_dateTimeLocal
' with the underscore?

Comment: @Pascal - I think I am missing some context to your question. I am going to guess you mean the underscore shouldn't be there due to a coding style convention? Maybe, I am not up to speed with the best JS coding practices, I tend to make all my private vars start with underscore. If you're asking from a functional perspective, the code functions as expected, which can be viewed and run from the plunker link in my answer.

Comment: Its not about style. Your binding expression {{dateTimeLocal}} is bound to this._dateTimeLocal = new Date(); which has an underscore. I do not understand why this works at all!?

Comment: @Pascal: Ah ok, I think I understand where the confusion is coming from. As you know C#, the simplest translation is 'dateTimeLocal' with a type of string is a property and '_dateTimeLocal' with a type of DateTime is a field. Typescript supports [Accessors](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) and that is where 'dateTimeLocal' comes from, note the 'get' and 'set' keywords on what appear to be functions in the bottom of the code pasted above, this is the TypeScript syntax. I did this because the HTML control isn't a DateTime but a String, so the Accessors deals with that.

Comment: Ah I did not know that dateTimeLocal is a getter. Haven`t fully scrolled down ;-) Now I understand it. Grabs value from private class field.