# Angular 2 Doesn't support input type="datetime-local"

Tags: html, angular, input, property-binding

I have noticed that angular 2 property bind doesnt work when using `input type="datetime-local"` is there any solution or workaround in order to bind input date with seconds to a property?

Comment: this should help you http://blog.johanneshoppe.de/2016/10/angular-2-how-to-use-date-input-controls-with-angular-forms/

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546447/bind-an-input-with-type-datetime-local-to-a-date-property-in-angular-2