# How do I set my HTML5 datetime-local input field to the current local date-time in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, datetime

I browsed through a few old questions here but most of them are about Angular 2 beta/RC versions which didn't ship with the date pipe.

I got closer with [THIS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546447/bind-an-input-with-type-datetime-local-to-a-date-property-in-angular-2) from Dec 2015 which suggested the following solution:

```
<input type="datetime-local" [ngModel]="datetime" (ngModelChange)="datetime = $event" name="datetime">

constructor() {
    this.datetime = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 16);
}
```

This almost worked correctly as it outputs the current datetime as: `02-06-2017 05:02 AM` where the date is correct but not the time. The local datetime here is `02-06-2017 10:48 AM`.

I haven't configured the default timezone anywhere in Angular. Need I do that  or is there a better solution to this problem? Also, it might be possible to implement the built in `date pipe` but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/NoIxFY7d7XltEc3brNSU?p=preview) demo

To show current local date-time you just have to simply create an ISO like string as follows:

```
this.datetime = this.datetime.getFullYear() + '-' + 
("0" + (this.datetime.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) 
+ '-' + ("0" + this.datetime.getDate()).slice(-2) 
+ 'T' + this.datetime.getHours() + ':' + this.datetime.getMinutes();
```

Feel free to comment and let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to recheck. This only correctly outputs the time but not the date. On June 4, it shows May 5. So the month is 1 less and the day is 1 more than what it should be. If I add 1 to getMonth as `datetime.getMonth()+1` and remove `+1` from getDate as `datetime.getDate()`, the input field doesn't accept it. The console reports the error: `The specified value "2017-51-04T15:30" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".`. Any ideas, friend?

Comment: Sorry @anonym had added 1 to getDate() instead of getMonth(). Now it is fixed. Please try and let me know if u still have issues

Comment: Like I mentioned in the comment, I did try adding 1 to getMonth() and not getDate(), and it reported the error. But now it works like a charm! Thanks a lot again.