# Angular 10: Formatting date in html

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following interface with a property `dueOn` which is a `Date`:

```
export interface ListItem {
    id: number;
    description: string;
    done: boolean;
    steps: Step[];
    dueOn: Date;
}
```

It has values like `dueOn: new Date("2020-08-01")` or `dueOn: new Date()`.

In my HTML view, I tried to use the datepipe to format it:

```
<input type="datetime-local" [(ngModel)]="listItem.dueOn" value="{{listItem.dueOn | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}">
```

I expected the output of this to be `2020-08-01` or `2020-07-06` but I get:

> Sat Aug 01 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)

> Mon Jul 06 2020 15:38:45 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)

Did I forget something or why isn't it being formatted correctly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the look of it ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546447/bind-an-input-with-type-datetime-local-to-a-date-property-in-angular-2)) you should either use yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm or type="date" to get it to display correctly. It seems like yyyy-MM-dd doesn't mash well with the type="datetime-local".

Comment: Thanks, your answer led me to the solution: `<input type="datetime-local" [ngModel]="listItem.dueOn | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'" (ngModelChange)="listItem.dueOn = $event" />` :)